# Making a view for tables with overlapping IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two tables `Cat` and `Dog`

Table `Cat` has the following columns: `id`, `name`, `weight`, `height`, `<special columns just for cat>`

Table `Dog` has the following columns: `id`, `name`, `weight`, `height`, `<special columns just for dog>`

And we want to create an `Animal` view: `id`, `name`, `weight`, `height`.

The datatypes are the same. Both `id` start at 0.

The simple option with overlapping `id`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Animal(id, name, weight, height) as
(SELECT
    id,
    name, 
    weight,
    height
FROM Cat)
UNION
(SELECT
    id,
    name, 
    weight,
    height
FROM Dog);
```

But we need some sort of primary key in the Animal table, and a way to refer back to them as a Cat or Dog if needed.

So I created this alternative which allows us to create a primary key out of `id` and `type`. But type is a varchar, so maybe it's not that efficient. Is there a better approach to this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Animal(id, type, name, weight, height) as
(SELECT
    id,
    "Cat",
    name, 
    weight,
    height
FROM Cat)
UNION
(SELECT
    id,
    "Dog",
    name, 
    weight,
    height
FROM Dog);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column specifying the type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Animal as
    SELECT id, name,  weight, height, 'Cat' as type
    FROM Cat
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, weight, height, 'Dog' as type
    FROM Dog;
```

The unique key is then the combination of `type` and `id`.

Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `FROM` clause for views.  That makes it a little complicated to add a unique row number for each row (it is possible).  So, I would recommend just sticking with the composite unique key.

Comment: I assume your example is missing a "type" column in the Animal view, correct? Could you clarify what "as type" does?

Comment: There does not seem to be any difference between "'Cat'" or "'Cat' as type"

Comment: @Lucas . . . Listing the columns is not needed, so I just removed them.  You should use single quotes for string constants.  That is the SQL standard.

Comment: Whats the relevance of the as type? Why not simply 'Cat' or 'Dog', instead of 'Cat' as type?

Comment: *That should be "in views".* No such restriction. [sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e165159edb08e6049042292a810970b1)

Comment: @Akina . . . I guess version 8.0 fixed that too.  I hadn't noticed.

Comment: *I guess version 8.0 fixed that* 5.7.?? (I don't remember precisely) fixed.